# an apparent "inconsistency" in lorentz transformations?

Tags: special-relativity

why the Lorentz transformations forbid passing to a reference system with the speed equal to that of light despite there are particles (photons) traveling at this speed? in other words I see the fact that the Lorentz transformations forbid placing oneself in an inertial system that travels at the speed of light (due to the cancellation of the denominator $1-\beta^2$) and that there is a photon that travels at this speed, which is a contradiction. Generally the explanation is that an observer cannot have zero mass. Despite this I see the possibility of having a
luminary system coinciding with the existence of a particle traveling at the speed of light, hence the contradiction that I said above. Can anyone explain to me the right point of view that I need to adopt?

Comment: A photon doesn't have a rest frame because it obeys $\mathrm{d}s^2=0$, [so can't measure time or space](https://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/811:_Starlight).

Comment: I also was surprised of this singularity, and tried to obtain Lorentz transformation from the invariance of the wave equation considering general change of coordinates. I only arrived at the fact that the transformation itself shall obey the wave equation, whose solution is generally a wavepacket travelling at light speed.